# Dealing with compatibility / errors in running Python2.7 script that has leading zeros on unix server via cronjob

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, shell, cron

I am trying to get an old Python script running that interacts with a lot of scripts all written in Python 2.7 ... upgrading it all is absolutely not happening, so I need to get around an error.

One module (reply.py) called by the main script (listener.py) has some time parameters in it, with leading zeros, which I presume are causing this error:

```
[myuser@server ~]$ python2.7 /home/myuser/public_html/app_project/listener.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/public_html/app_project/listener.py", line 10, in <module>
    from modules import reply
  File "/home/myuser/public_html/app_project/modules/reply.py", line 144
    if now_time >= time(09,00) and now_time <= time(17,00):
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
[myuser@server ~]$ python2.7 /home/myuser/public_html/app_project/listener.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/public_html/app_project/listener.py", line 10, in <module>
    from modules import reply
  File "/home/myuser/public_html/app_project/modules/reply.py", line 144
    if now_time >= time(09,00) and now_time <= time(17,00):
```

But the thing I am confused about, is that the main script is set to execute in Python2.7 ... which should be fine with the leading zeros?

The workflow is...

cronjob calls shell script to check python process (listener.py) is running:

```
#!/bin/bash
pid_file='/home/myuser/public_html/app_project/listener.pid'
if [ ! -s "$pid_file" ] || ! kill -0 $(cat $pid_file) > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo $$ > "$pid_file"
  exec /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/myuser/public_html/app_project/listener.py
fi
```

So the main executable (listener.py) is run in Python2.7 ... so I don't understand what the issue with leading zeroes is in the module (reply.py)...?

Is it because the module (reply.py) is executing via Python3 somehow? Is that why it doesn't like the leading zeros? Or is the 'invalid token' error about something else?

Any advice to get around this would be very much appreciated.

Please note, I do not want to change code extensively (this is not the only piece of code in the app that would have to change, i.e. getting rid of leading zeros and upgrading it to Python3 would take a long, long time to do right), I just want to ensure it all executes fine in 2.7. There are no reasons otherwise to upgrade the app to Python3.

Comment: A leading zero in Python 2 would have represented an octal value. So 09 can't possibly be valid in either Python 2 or Python 3

Comment: @AlbertWinestein thanks ... interesting... so maybe my code needs re-doing to remove all the leading zeros? I could easily be mistaken as I am not great with Python, but thought leading zeros were OK in P2.7 like this. If you're certain then feel free to post this as an answer?

Comment: @AlbertWinestein may I also ask... if leading zeros aren't permitted, then how do I represent midnight, i.e. 00,00?

Comment: Just don't use leading zeroes - i.e., 0,0. Also, consider the significant difference, for example, between 17 and 017 in Python 2.7

Comment: Thanks @AlbertWinestein (make this an answer and I'll mark correct?) ... but what about 22,00 for 10pm... should that be 22,0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to Python 3, a leading zero for an integer token indicated that the value was octal - e.g., 07. The leading zero alone was an indicator that what followed was octal

In Python 3, leading zeroes can be used for octal values but you need an additional qualifier - e.g., 0o7

A token of 09 would not be valid in either Python 2 or 3

Comment: Can you just clarify if 22,00 is OK? I am assuming yes... but wanted to check?

Comment: Yes - 22,00 is OK. I can't explain the rationale behind this but 00 (or indeed any number of zeroes) is equivalent to zero. In a nutshell, a token beginning with zero cannot be succeeded by any integer other than zero

Comment: OK, got you. However, isn't 00,00 also OK then?

Comment: Yes - 00,00 would be OK